# Force a DialogFragment to remain on screen

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-dialogfragment

I want to show a custom progress dialog using a DiaogFragment and I want it to not dismiss when the user clicks out of its bound. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your dialog as non cancelable, if you are using DialogFragment

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
YourDialogFragment fragment = new YourDialogFragment();
fragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```